# How Switch knows if the packet reached it's destination?

Tags: switch, network, networking, lan

In a Lan connected using switch, For the first time if the sender sends a data to the destination, then the switch will send the data to all the devices in the network, and the devices will have to accept whether the data is meant for them. For the second time, the switch don't broadcast the data as it did, because it stored the mac address of the destination device from the first time broadcast, so it sends the data directly to the destination device.

This all makes sense. But in the first time when it broadcasted the data, how the switch knows that the destination device has got the data. Does the destination device send a acknowledgement to the switch that it got the data? If so what kind of acknowledgement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethernet does not have any acknowledgement system. The switch transmits the frame and moves on. It has no way to know the frame was received, nor does it care.

If the destination never sends a frame, the switch will never learn where it is. It will continue "unicast flooding" that traffic.

Comment: Thanks . Getting to know bout switches

Comment: @Allan There are some circumstances where you might have to wait for the MAC to age out if you move a device. Typically though, if you do something like move a laptop into another socket, it's going to send a DHCP request when you reconnect it, and the switch will then know where it is.